# Подскажите, как добавить проверку reCaptcha и почему не приходит приклепленный файл? в php не сильна от слова совсем

Tags: php, form, recaptcha

Сейчас форма отправляется и без нажатия на капчу, а письма приходят без вложений

```
                <form method="post" action="file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="feedback">
                    <p><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Телефон"></p>
                    <p><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
                    <p><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Сообщение"></textarea></p>
                    <p><input type="file" name="files" size="30"></p>
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf1clseAAAAABUVVi_hmW343oxu92n2RbV4enxu" id="recaptchaError"></div>
                    <div id="frm-result"></div>
                    <p style="font-size: 10px">Отправляя запрос, я соглашаюсь с <button class="button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModaltwo">политикой конфиденциальности</button></p>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" value="Отправить">
                </form>
```

```
<?php
function send_mail()
{
$name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name']);
}
{
$email = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['email']);
}
$message = '<b>Имя: </b>'.$_REQUEST['name'].'<br><b>Телефон: </b>'.$_REQUEST['phone'].'<br> <b>Электронный адрес: </b>'.$_REQUEST['email'].'<br><b>Сообщение: </b>'.$_REQUEST['message'].'<br><b>Файл: </b>'.$_REQUEST['files'];

include "class.phpmailer.php";// подключаем класс

$arr = json_decode($rsp, TRUE);
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->From = $_REQUEST['email'];
$mail->FromName = $_REQUEST['name'];
$mail->AddAddress('info.setonix@yandex.ru');
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $_POST['title'];

if(isset($_FILES['files']))
{
if($_FILES['files']['error'] == 0)
{
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['files']['name']);
}
}
$mail->Body = $message;
if (!$mail->Send()) die ('Mailer Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo);
{
echo '<center><b>Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения<br><a href=index.html>Нажмите</a>, чтобы вернуться на главную страницу';
}

if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) send_mail();
?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Добавила описание

Comment: Первый же результат с гугла решает проблемы с капчей. https://xdan.ru/proverka-recaptcha-2-0-s-pomoshchyu-php-i-javascript.html. Документация - https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php?hl=ru. С phpmailer ответ можно найти там же (в поисковике)